# Python carriage return \r selectively not working

Tags: python

So I'm working on a loading bar, the bar is supposed to spread to the end of the line and then disappear (all on 1 line) as if it were travelling off screen.The carriage return thing works in my first while loop (as the loading bar enters the screen). My problem is when it's supposed to "leave the screen" the '/r' thing doesn't return the carriage and puts each bar iteration on a new line ruining the effect. This can be found in my second while loop in the provided code snippet:

```
import time

s=1
f=1
while True:
    while s <= 128:
        loadbar = ('█'*s)
        print(loadbar, end='\r')
        time.sleep(0.01)
        s=s+1
    while f <= 128:
        loadbar = ' ' + loadbar[:-1]
        print(loadbar, end='\r')
        time.sleep(0.01)
        f=f+1
    s=1
    f=1
```

I've looked everywhere for similar issues, also I am running the script from python 3 via a batch file so I know it isn't a problem with IDLE Shell because I know IDLE Shell normally ignores carriage returns (at least from experience). Please let me know if any further details are needed and all help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is your terminal 128 wide? Could be that your string is one character too long, try changing the while loops to use `< 128`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in a comment, the problem is that your terminal size is likely not 128. Better to not guess the right number.

Use instead the [os.get_terminal_size()](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/os.html?highlight=get_terminal#os.get_terminal_size) function or the [shutil.get_terminal_size()](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/shutil.html#shutil.get_terminal_size) function which tell you the size of your terminal: you get both width and height, here called columns and lines, so what you need is the columns.

Here an example working code based on the example you posted which should do what you want (I just switched `'█'` with `"="`):

```
import time
import os

s=1
f=1
n_cols = os.get_terminal_size().columns

while True:
    while s <= n_cols:
        loadbar = '='*s
        print(loadbar, end='\r')
        time.sleep(0.01)
        s=s+1
    while f <= n_cols:
        loadbar = ' '*f + "="*(n_cols-f)
        print(loadbar, end='\r')
        time.sleep(0.01)
        f=f+1
    s=1
    f=1
```

Comment: Your solution produces the same problem as before but your diagnosis is correct, I can see that it works perfectly if i slightly extend the terminal window. Your method is helpful but I'll just make the line extend to 127 or 126. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: That is curious, I tested my solution and works well. Maybe there is some OS setting. If you want to use my solution, probably is enough to let the inner `while` loops run with `<` instead of `<=`

Comment: Tried that as well but still same problem, _spooky_. My solution is good enough for me but maybe I'll revisit it later and try to figure out what voodoo is living in my code.